# hide imported child component on hover using styled-components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Like the title says, this works with styled components sitting within the same js file (provided they are procedural-ordered above). But with imported child components I can't get it to work.

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

// Components
import Bars from "../path/Bars.js";
import BarsHover from "../path/BarsHover.js";

// Variables
import { colors } from "../../path/index.js";

//============================================ styles =============================================
const DivBars = styled(Bars)``;
const DivBarsHover = styled(BarsHover)``;
const DivWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  width: 20rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;

  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  &:hover ${DivBars} {
    display: none;
  }

  &:hover ${DivBarsHover} {
    display: block;
  }
`;
//=========================================== component ===========================================
const ParentComponent = props => {
  return (
    <DivContainer>
      <DivBars fullBarWidth={"100%"} fractionBarWidth={"70%"} barColor={colors.niagara} />
      <DivBarsHover fullBarWidth={"100%"} fractionBarWidth={"70%"} barColor={colors.gallery2} />
    </DivContainer>
  );
};
```

export default ParentComponent;

Comment: Are you saying `Bars` and `BarsHover`, which are imported, can't be hidden, but `DivBars` and `DivBarsHover` can? Your question (if there is one) is a little unclear to me.

Comment: (Edited the question for better clerity): no, I can't get any of them to hide. I've tried with both `&:hover ${Bars} {display:none}` and using `&:hover ${DivBars} {display:none}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think *this* [caveat](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#caveat) is the cause:

> ...wrapping `A` in a styled() factory makes it eligible for
>   interpolation **-- just make sure the wrapped component passes along
>   className**.
>
> ```
> class A extends React.Component {
>   render() {
>     return <div className={this.props.className} />
>   }
> }
>
> const StyledA = styled(A)``
>
> const B = styled.div`
>   ${StyledA} {
>   }
> `
> ```

**NOTE**: Ensure the `className` prop is propagated *all the way* to the component being referenced in the case that it isn't a direct descendent.

[image: Edit fast-paper-i0tg0]

Comment: for some weird reason it still didn't work for me (only difference is I'm using `import x from...` and `not import { x } from...`. I was however able to get it to work after wrapping those components in an individual child div, and then calling that child div to hide on the parent div.

Comment: Ah the difference for me is because I have one more nested parent in between is why my code couldn't see it (didn't think that would make a difference). Anyway well done and this answers the question. I do recommend editing the answer code to match the code in the sandbox (as the sandbox code may disappear in the future).

Comment: The code in solution is a copy from `styled-components` documentation and I don't change my sandboxes once answered on SO unless I need to update answer here. Glad it worked for you!